# How to understand weight lexicographical orderings and degree lexicographical orderings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

Let $A=\{a_1,\ldots , a_n\}$.

(a) Let $w: {A^*}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{+}$ be a mapping that associates a positive integer with each letter. Define the $\mathbf{weight\ ordering} $ $\leq_{w}$ induced by $w$ as follows:
  \begin{align}\nonumber
   x\leq_{w}y\ \text{ if } \ w(x)\leq_{w}w(y).
  \end{align}
  Here $w$ is extended to a mapping from $A^*$ into $\mathbb{N}$ by taking $w(1):=0$ and $w(xa):=w(x)+w(a)$ for all $x\in A^*, a\in A$.

(b) The $\mathbf{lexicographical\ ordering}$ $\leq_{l}$ on $A^*$ is defined as following: $x\leq_{l}y$ if there is a non-empty element $z$ such that
    \begin{align}\nonumber
x=yz\ \text{ or }\ x=ua_iv\ \text{ and }\ y=ua_jz
\end{align}
    for some $u,v,z \in A^*$, and $i,j\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ satisfying $i\leq j$.

The ordering $\leq_{wl}$ is called $\mathbf{weight\ lexicographical\  ordering}$ if it satisfies the condition $(a)$ and condition $(b)$.

Maybe we can define the $\mathbf{degree\ ordering} $ $\leq_{d}$ induced by $w$ as follows:
  \begin{align}\nonumber
   x\leq_{d}y\ \text{ if } \ \mathbf{deg}(x)\leq_{d}\mathbf{deg}(y).
  \end{align}
Then the degree ordering is a weight ordering.

But I don't know whether the above definition of the degree ordering is corect?

Comment: What do you mean by degree?  Degree is not mentioned in the definitions.

Comment: @William Elliot, I have edit my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why is 1 in A* (w(1) = 0)?

Comment: What is the point of degrees?  The definition of weighted dictionary order is complete as is.  Is there something about that order you do not understand?  You have not defined deg(x) nor what a degree ordering is nor how degrees relate to weights nor why a degree ordering is needed.

Comment: @ William Elliot 1is the empty word. Let $A=\{x_1,x_2\}$. Then we can get two words ${x_1}^2x_2$, $x_1x_2$, the degree of the first word is 3, the second is 2

Comment: Let A = {a b}. Is the degree of aba two?  By degree quasiordering,

Comment: Let A = {a b}. Is the degree of aba two?  By degree quasiordering, a <= b and b <= a.  By dictionary order a < b and by weigh quasiorder anything can happen depending upon the weights.  How are the weights inducing the degree order?  What are you trying to do?  Defined a weighted degree order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a degree lexicographically order replace the weighted
quasiorder in the definition of the weighted lexicographically
order with the degree quasiorder, x <=_d y when deg(x) <= deg(y).

Comment: From your answer, dou you agree the   degree lexicographically order is  weighted lexicographically order?

Comment: @Daisy.  It is weighted by the degree.